# Getting component_validate_password error in logfile

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error log in RedHat linux 8, mysql 8.0.34.
I could see that I do have the file and permission established in my server.

`023-09-19T03:36:12.880410Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-001126 - Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_validate_password.so' (errno: 0 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_validate_password.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied)`

```
[root@MYSQLDB01 plugin]# ls -l componen*

rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   21320 Jun 22 08:36 component_audit_api_message_emit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1879936 Jun 22 08:36 component_keyring_file.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   29400 Jun 22 08:36 component_log_filter_dragnet.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   37488 Jun 22 08:36 component_log_sink_json.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20952 Jun 22 08:36 component_log_sink_syseventlog.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   51216 Jun 22 08:36 component_mysqlbackup.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16520 Jun 22 08:36 component_query_attributes.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   47296 Jun 22 08:36 component_reference_cache.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   59440 Jun 22 08:36 component_validate_password.so
```

While installing audit plugin, I might have messed up. I ran several cmake. It could have cause issue to the MySQL. Any help to resolve this is much appreciated.